# Zoom in and out without a mouse wheel

Tags: 3d-view

I am using blender on a tablet, for those times when I can't plug a mouse into the tablet, I would like to still be able to zoom in and out on the viewport.

What ways are there to zoom in and out other than using the mouse wheel? I can't find any buttons or input boxes in the user interface that control the zoom of the view port.

Is it possible to enter a value somewhere for how far in or out the viewport is zoomed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest way to zoom with a tablet, in my opinion, is to use **Emulate 3 Button Mouse** from *File > User Preferences > Input*.

This allows you to zoom in and out with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image]</kbd> drag.

Then you can also orbit with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image]</kbd> drag. And you can pan with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image]</kbd> drag.

[image: Emulate 3 Button Mouse]

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of ways to control the viewport zoom without access to a three-button mouse:

- You can use keyboard to zoom in and out by using <kbd>numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>numpad -</kbd>. If you don't have a numpad on your keyboard, you can set Blender to emulate the numpad under *User Preferences > Input > Emulate Numpad*.
- If you are using Blender on a tablet (or on a computer with a touchscreen), you can zoom in and out by using two fingers on the screen and moving them closer or farther away from each other, just like with other mobile applications.

***That being said***, you can purchase a three button mouse separately, and use that to manipulate the viewport. If you are going to be using Blender heavily on a device with no third-mouse-button, this can make an *enormous* difference. For tablets specifically, you can get a wireless mouse with Bluetooth connectivity.

Comment: No number pad a notebook/laptop

Answer (score 3):

## Click on contact

Setup your the graphics tablet to click when the tip is pressed. Then the other two buttons can be set to right and middle click. Now just use the default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>middle-mouse</kbd> key-binding (can be customised user preferences).

- On GNU/Linux see the "TPCButton" and "ButtonM" settings in `man wacom`.

## Gestures

Additionally/Alternatively you can use a gesture-recognition application to convert gestures into keyboard/Blender commands.

- Here on GNU/Linux I use [Easystroke](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/).

Answer (score 0):

Today with Blender 3.3.1 you can go in `Edit`→`Preferences...`→`Keymap`. There you can tweak and bind a lot of Blender actions to keys and buttons in various Blender views.

I use a graphic tablet. F13 is mapped to the undo key of my tablet and right-click on a pen button for zoom. The later binding is very time saving in my workflow.
[image: Blender Preferences Keymap]
*I added these bindings in the General drop-down.*